# Экранизация классики

Tags: литература

В связи с выходом американской "Анны Карениной" в сети стали появляться такие вот перлы:

[image]

Что вы вообще думаете относительно экранизации классики: нужна она или только отупляет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вполне согласна с предыдущим ответом. Добавлю как учитель. Если раньше мы сетовали на то, что дети не читают, то сейчас они и фильмы не смотрят. Поэтому, когда все-таки берут книгу в руки, особенно классику 19 века,  им сложно представить то,о чем  написано. После прочтения в классе часто смотрим фильм по произведению. Обязательно должно быть визуальное сопровождение! Иначе такого напредставляют, ведь дети не знают значения элементарных слов! И 2 урока литературы в неделю не могут заменить ежедневного чтения.  Вот недавно с шестиклассниками посмотрели некоторые эпизоды из "Майской ночи.." по Гоголю. *А вот это дети коромысло, а это плетень, веретено, хата и т.д.* А еще литературу хотят с русским совместить... Совсем иностранцами дети расти будут. Поэтому фильмы очень нужны. И даже если все будут читать и понимать.

Кино и литература -  это разные виды искусства, со своими средствами, возможностями. Бывает интересно сравнить свое представление о книге с авторским (авторами фильма)видением. Хотя я не люблю портить впечатление. Если сначала прочитала, то фильм всегда мне кажется хуже.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, экранизировать надо, но умело. Чем выше талант писателя, тем выше должен быть талант сценариста, режиссёра, актёров. Книга Фурманова и фильм братьев Васильевых - небо и земля (земля и небо!). Но чаще всего, писатель оказывается выше режиссёра, однако это не значит, что "не надо было браться за оружие" (Г. В. Плеханов В. И. Ленину). Книга и фильм - два взгляда на одно и то же двумя личностями, и уже это интересно само по себе. Режиссёр в точности не может следовать за писателем, у него меньше возможностей, но тонкий режиссёр имеет много шансов стать вровень с автором.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, есть редкие случаи, когда экранизация лучше оригинального произведения. Например, сериал "Петербургские тайны" по двухтомнику Крестовского "Петербургские трущобы".
Или когда экранизация становится киноклассикой сама по себе, как стало с "Войной и миром" или "Собачьим сердцем".
Главное, чтобы там не играл Безруков))))))))))))
Но я категорически против западных экранизаций нашей классики.

Comment: Да, Петербургские тайны были замечательны. Кстати, все сериалы крутят по всем каналам, а этого не видно... Насчет западных экранизаций полностью с Вами согласна.